# How can I create a button using mrtk 2.4 and Unity 2019.4 (AR for Hololens) with a custom shape?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uibutton, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

**Hello**.
I'm trying to **create a button** which is **shaped in a custom, trapezoid-ish shape**.
so far I've tried manipulating colliders on regular *MRTK - toolbox* buttons, and using
a 3d model as the button (like in *Hand Tracking Example 1*) with the scripts that the
documentation suggests (*NearInteractionTouchable* & *PressableButton*) so far with no success.
So, is there maybe a different way to **create a custom shaped button for my Hololens UI?**

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After my test,  the guide [How to make a button from scratch](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Button.html#how-to-make-a-button-from-scratch) works fine for me. If you got that issue while using this document, did you adjust the `Press Setting` after adding the `PressableButton` component? The default distance data may be invalid, you need to reassign the distance values according to the actual size of your 3D model. If it still cannot work after trying it, please feel free to feedback.